# SwiftUI Search bar unable to product diagnostic error

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a search bar using this tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-search-bar .

I can get the search bar to display and to take text but it does nothing with that text because it's not used at this stage to filter.

When I try to use it to filter my list of products - taken from Firestore - it throws a `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report` error.

```
struct ProductList: View {
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    // ProductsModel() is the Class that this structure is looking at. If anything in ProductsModel changes, then - because it is an ObservableObject - then this structure/view ProductList will update with the new information.
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ProductsModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                
                HStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductCreationView()){Text("Add Product")}
                NavigationLink(destination: Initialinfo()){Text("Help")}
                } //Navigation Links
                
                SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                
                List(viewModel.product_fire.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.product_name.contains(searchText) })){ product in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product))
                    {ItemRow(product: product).navigationBarTitle("Products", displayMode: .inline)}
                    }.onAppear(){
                        self.viewModel.fetchData()
                    }
                
                
                // Create a list of all products where each product is given a link that points to the specific product detail page as well as the description taken from the ItemRow view for that product.
                // This displays as : Product Name/Link
                //                      Product Brand
                //                    ...
                List(viewModel.product_fire, id:\.product_name) { product in
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product))
                {ItemRow(product: product).navigationBarTitle("Products", displayMode: .inline)}
                }.onAppear(){
                    self.viewModel.fetchData()
                }
```

If I comment out the code for the filtered version it displays fine and pulls all products from the database and displays with Name/Link and Brand as a pair for each product as one large list.

From reading other problems RE this error - but none about search bars - it seems to be a problem with { } placement etc but no amount of tinkering has helped.

Edit 1:
I created a function that takes in the searchText and then searches the Firestore for documents that have the documentID equal to the searchText (these should be unique).

```
func singleData(searchText: String){
    db.collection("Products").whereField("code", isEqualTo: searchText)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The List and NavigationLinks in the `ProductList` view have been swapped out for:

```
        Text("Test").onAppear(){
            self.viewModel.singleData(searchText: String)
        }
```

with the intention that if the searchText is an existing document then it will pass that code on to the `ProductDetail` view and take the user straight there, and remove the need for the Lists.
It prints the product data to the console but I am running into problems trying to return the value back to the view as it gives a void type error.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you run the code in the simulator or on a device to get more meaningful errors?

Comment: It wouldn’t build and just kept red flagging this error as the cause of the build failed on both the Emulator and a real device

Comment: You should really move that filtering logic to your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis in `filter`

```
List(viewModel.product_fire.filter{ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.product_name.contains(searchText) }){ product in
```

But it would be best if you just get filtered objects from your `ViewModel`

Comment: My viewModel is a class that currently just fetches the data and passes it all to the List. Am I right in thinking you are suggesting to reduce the data down in the class before passing it to the list? If so would the flow be to take the searchText, pass that to the fetchData function and only fetch the data that matches the searchText? And then return that to be used by the List?